# Show that there has to be an orbit with at least $3$ elements

Tags: group-theory

Let $H \leq A_4$ be a subgroup of $6$ elements. $H$ acts on $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ by $\sigma \cdot i = \sigma(i)$. Show that for $H$ to act on $X$ there has to be an orbit with at least $3$ elements.

---

This is what I could think of:

Since $H$ is a subgroup of $A_4$ and it contains 6 elements there has to be a $3$-cycle and so there has to be an orbit with at least $3$ elements. For example, if the $3$-cycle is $(123)$ and we look at the orbit containing $1$ we find $(123)(1)=2 \in X$, $(123)(2)=3 \in X$. So The orbit contains at least $1,2$ and $3$.

I'm really uncertain about this, so I hope someone could shed some light on this matter.

Comment: What is $\;A_4\;$ ? Because if it is, as usually denoted, the alternating group of order $\;12\;$ then it has no subgroup of order six... Perhaps it is only a "What if" exercise?

Comment: @Joanpemo, yes it's a what if exercise, because eventually we have to show why such an H cannot exist. $A_4$ is indeed the alternating group of order $12$.

Comment: With what you wrote you've already solved your question: you've already shown there has to be an orbit with at least three elements. What else do you want?

Comment: @Joanpemo, I wasn't completely sure. I was hoping for someone to confirm or to provide some insight leading to a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Ch I think that's as elegant as it can get. Behold that you're assuming very little, for example: that since $\;3\,\mid\,|H|\;$ then $\;H\;$ must contain a three-cycle...but since $\;H\lhd A_4\;$ then it would have to contain *all* three cycles, which is ridiculous. Anyway, I think your way is alright.